# How to parse a declarative language like QML to QWidgets .ui XML format code?

Tags: xml, qt, qml

As I am the fan of QML so I want to make a QtCreator plugin so that I may be able to write QWidgets ui in QML *like* code. QML is readable and takes less real-state.
My question is how can I convert the following QML *like* code to the following .ui XML code.

My proposed QML *like* code:

```
QWidget {
    name: "centralWidget"
    QPushButton {
        name: "pushButton"
        geometry: {
            x: 10
            y: 20
            width: 150
            height: 50
        }
        text: "Hello World!"
    }
}
```

.ui XML code:

```
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>20</y>
      <width>150</width>
      <height>50</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Hello World!</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
```

I would be thankful if someone point me to the right direction or share a sample code/library please!

Comment: see https://github.com/KDAB/DeclarativeWidgets

Comment: I already know about that great project https://github.com/KDAB/DeclarativeWidgets, here what I want to do is to make a plugin for qt creator to view live changes I make in ui using qml like code. In fact I want to parse the qml like code I have mentioned in the question, translate it into xml and forward it to QFormBuilder(https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qformbuilder.html) to view the live changes.

Comment: I don't need the javascript part of the QML, I only need the part of QML which is used for declaring ui.

Comment: As you point out the main task is to parse QML since converting it to XML is easier if you have the data, IMHO I think that Qt does not have a class (at least public) that does that, so the Qt tag does not make sense since The question is general: How to parse a declarative language to XML

Comment: Yes you are right, I simply searching for a way to parse declarative language to qwidgets .ui xml format code.

Comment: For example, I wonder what languages do you want to use? Do you know all the rules of QML? What properties do you want to parse? Not all QObject properties are accepted by the .ui

Comment: I want to parse only those properties which are supported by the Qt Designer. In fact, the QML like code and XML code created by Designer would be essentially same but different in syntax only! For me, QML is easy to read while xml is not.

Comment: I understand, but your question is of the same type of "How to convert json to csv", and there is no general answer so you have to establish clear rules in the json format, the same must happen in this case, plus you must create a editor that recognizes the syntax. Finally my comments are only meant to give you an overview of what you should evaluate to make your plugin :-)., bye

Comment: @eyllanesc Can you please have a look over this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55355246/how-to-find-only-those-properties-of-a-widget-which-are-shown-in-the-qt-designer