# How to find only those properties of a widget which are shown in the Qt Designer?

Tags: qt, qwidget, qt-designer

How can I find **only those properties** of a widget (e.g. QPushButton) **which Qt Designer shows in the Property Editor**?
I can find all properties including those which are not shown in the Qt Designer using the following code:

```
// Print all available properties of a Widget:
qDebug()<<qPrintable("Widget: QPushButton");
QObject *object = new QPushButton;
const QMetaObject *metaobject = object->metaObject();
for (int i=0; i<metaobject->propertyCount(); ++i) {
    QMetaProperty metaproperty = metaobject->property(i);
    const char *name = metaproperty.name();
    QVariant value = object->property(name);
    qDebug()<<qPrintable("\n" + QString(name) + "\n" + QString(value.typeName()));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[isDesignable()](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qmetaproperty.html#isDesignable) should tell if the property will be shown in Qt Designer.

As stated in the Qt [Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html):

> The DESIGNABLE attribute indicates whether the property should be visible in the property editor of GUI design tool (e.g., Qt Designer). Most properties are DESIGNABLE (default true). Instead of true or false, you can specify a boolean member function.

Also it seems that read-only properties are not shown in Designer.

Following your example:

```
    // Print all available properties of a Widget:
    qDebug()<<qPrintable("Widget: QPushButton");
    QPushButton *object = new QPushButton(this);
    const QMetaObject *metaobject = object->metaObject();
    for (int i=0; i<metaobject->propertyCount(); ++i) {
        QMetaProperty metaproperty = metaobject->property(i);
        const char *name = metaproperty.name();
        QVariant value = object->property(name);
        bool isReadOnly = metaproperty.isReadable() && !metaproperty.isWritable();
        bool isWinModal = metaproperty.name() == QString("windowModality"); // removed windowModality manually
        if(!isReadOnly && metaproperty.isDesignable(object) && !isWinModal){
            qDebug() << metaproperty.name();
        }
    }
```

This prints:

```
Widget: QPushButton
objectName
enabled
geometry
sizePolicy
minimumSize
maximumSize
sizeIncrement
baseSize
palette
font
cursor
mouseTracking
tabletTracking
focusPolicy
contextMenuPolicy
acceptDrops
toolTip
toolTipDuration
statusTip
whatsThis
accessibleName
accessibleDescription
layoutDirection
autoFillBackground
styleSheet
locale
inputMethodHints
text
icon
iconSize
shortcut
checkable
autoRepeat
autoExclusive
autoRepeatDelay
autoRepeatInterval
autoDefault
default
flat
```

But there is a few caveats about this:

- Property visibility on Designer can be set on and off by other properties. For example `checked` property is designable only if boolean property `setCheckable` is set to true.

Extacted from QAbstractButton definition:

```
Q_PROPERTY(bool checkable READ isCheckable WRITE setCheckable)
Q_PROPERTY(bool checked READ isChecked WRITE setChecked DESIGNABLE isCheckable NOTIFY toggled USER true)
```

- So to achieve what you want I am ruling out read-only and `windowModality` properties but this is kind of hacky. I am not sure if there is better way of doing this.

Comment: It doesn't work as expected. For example, In the designer the following QPushButton properties are not shown but they are isDesignable: frameGeometry, normalGeometry, frameSize, childrenRect, etc

Comment: It seems that read-only properties like those you mentioned are never shown on Designer whether they are designable or not.

Comment: Maybe, you could modify your code to check if `isReadable() ` but not `isWritable()` and rule those out.

Comment: The following code eliminated many unrelated properties but still I can see some properties like windowModality, frameGeometry, normalGeometry, childrenRect, windowIcon, windowIconText, windowOpacity, windowModified etc. which are not shown in Qt Designer. These properties are shown ONLY for the root/parent widget of the application like QMainWindow or QWidget.
Code:

Comment: `QObject *object = new QPushButton;`

`const QMetaObject *metaobject = object->metaObject();`
`for (int i=0; i<metaobject->propertyCount(); ++i) {`
    `QMetaProperty metaproperty = metaobject->property(i);`
   ` if( metaproperty.isDesignable() && metaproperty.isWritable() ) {`
        `qDebug()<<qPrintable(QString(metaproperty.name()) + " : " + QString(metaproperty.typeName()));`
   ` }`
`}`

Comment: I also did what you suggested like I checked if `isReadable` but not `isWritable` but this rule out all `isDesignable` properties as they are both readable and writable.

Comment: I think your code is perfect because I have noticed that Qt Designer also use such kind of hacky approach, examples, see line no. 638 and 1907 in the following links: https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qttools/src/designer/src/lib/shared/qdesigner_propertysheet.cpp.html#638
https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qttools/src/designer/src/components/formeditor/qdesigner_resource.cpp.html#1907